# Does inheritance turn a class into an object?

Tags: java

So, for example. When I create a class;

```
 public class CPlogo extends JFrame{

 }
```

Does the class "CPlogo" now inherent an object or just the methods of the JFrame class?

I would love to know more about this, shoot me a few good tutorials if you have any please. I've watched the ones on YouTube already, but I still fail to understand...

Comment: Well,you can access all the variables & methods of JFrame (unless they are marked as public/protected as it is a single level inheritance).

Comment: Sometimes I wish there was a "fundamental misunderstanding" close reason. Stack Overflow is not the place to learn basic concepts about any language.

Comment: And the reason I say that is that "inherit an object" makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Inheritance in java is a mechanism in which one object acquires all
>   the properties and behaviors of parent object.
>
> The idea behind inheritance in java is that you can create new classes
>   that are built upon existing classes. When you inherit from an
>   existing class, you can reuse methods and fields of parent class, and
>   you can add new methods and fields also.
>
> Inheritance represents the IS-A relationship, also known as
>   parent-child relationship.

See [this](http://www.javatpoint.com/inheritance-in-java) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more information. Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks to you and everybody else! I enjoy new information. :) I've been reading this book called, "Big Java," but it lacks explanation in many areas. :/

Comment: Read Computer Programming in Java (by G.T Thampi). Awesome book for beginners.

Comment: And only $8! Much better than the $75 I had to spend on my school text book.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't create of **CPlogo**  however it accomodates non static state and behaviour of parent class.

Here also you have two cases:

```
Jfram cpl = new CplLogo();
```

// in above statement you strictly have object of  CplLogo but with methods which are available in JFrame class and overridden in CPLLOgo class.

And in below condition

```
 CplLogo = new CplLogo();
```

// CplLogo has both methods of parent and his own